# Почему очередь не передаёт данные через мютекс из процесса в поток?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, очередь

Почему очередь не передаёт данные через мютекс из процесса в поток ??

Вот код :

```
// Применить мьютекс. 
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

// В этом классе содежится общий ресурс (переменная Queue), 
// а также мьютекс(Mtx), управляющий доступом к ней.  
class SharedRes
{
    //static readonly Queue<string> data = new Queue<string>();

    public static Queue<string> data = new Queue<string>();

    public static Mutex Mtx = new Mutex();
}

// В этом потоке переменная SharedRes.Queue инкрементируется. 
class IncThread
{
    int num;
    public Thread Thrd;

    public IncThread(string name)
    {
        Thrd = new Thread(this.Run);
        Thrd.Name = name;
        Thrd.Start();
    }

    // Точка входа в поток.  
    void Run()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "ping",
            Arguments = "www.ya.ru",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (var pingProcess = new Process())
        {
            pingProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            pingProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
            pingProcess.Start();
            pingProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            // На этом методе будет ожидание завершения запущенного процесса.
            // При получении каждой новой порции данных
            // будет вызываться событие OutputDataReceived.
            pingProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Thrd.Name + " ожидает мютекс.");
    }

    private static void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Получить мьютекс. 
        SharedRes.Mtx.WaitOne();


        Console.WriteLine("Мы в потоке один");

        SharedRes.data.Enqueue(e.Data);
        //Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        using (var writer = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
            writer.WriteLine(e.Data);

        // Освободить мьютекс. 
        SharedRes.Mtx.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

// В этом потоке переменная SharedRes.Count декрементируеться. 
class DecThread
{
    int num;
    public Thread Thrd;

    public DecThread(string name)
    {
        Thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Run));
        Thrd.Name = name;
        Thrd.Start();
    }

    // ТОчка входа в поток.  
    void Run()
    {
        // Получить мьютекс. 
        SharedRes.Mtx.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Мы в потоке два");

        while (SharedRes.data.Count > 0)
                Console.WriteLine(SharedRes.data.Dequeue());

        // Освободить мьютекс. 
        SharedRes.Mtx.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

class MutexDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Construct three threads.  
        IncThread mt1 = new IncThread("Инкрементирующий поток");

        Thread.Sleep(1); // let the Increment thread start 

        DecThread mt2 = new DecThread("Декрементирующий поток");

        mt1.Thrd.Join();
        mt2.Thrd.Join();
    }
}
```

Вот вывод :

```
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mcs lovla_terminal7.cs 
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mono lovla_terminal7.exe 
Мы в потоке два
Мы в потоке один
Мы в потоке один
Мы в потоке один
Мы в потоке один
Мы в потоке один
Мы в потоке один
Мы в потоке один
Мы в потоке один
^C
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не передает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую разобрать все проблемы, которые я увидел в коде.

1. Я бы не использовал `Mutex` для такой задачи, как и `AutoResetEvent`, так как оба тяжелые, и если вход в некую область выполнения кода должен производиться одновременно только одним потоком, я бы использовал `ManualResetEventSlim` или просто `lock()` какого-нибудь общего объекта.

А `Mutex` я бы вообще оставил для кросс-процессной синхронизации, например, с помощью него можно сделать, чтобы нельзя было запустить 2 копии программы. Его именно для этого чаще всего и используют.

2. В вашем же случае второй поток стартует и пытается освободить еще пустую очередь, и сразу же завершается. **Проблема наверное была не в мьютексе.** Ну или я неправильно понял, как вы хотели, чтобы оно работало.

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы сначала один поток заполнил очередь, а второй потом ее освободил, то вы неправильно вызываете потоки, у вас должно получиться что-то такое.

```
static void Main()
{
    IncThread mt1 = new IncThread("Инкрементирующий поток");
    mt1.Thrd.Join();

    DecThread mt2 = new DecThread("Декрементирующий поток");
    mt2.Thrd.Join();
}
```

И да, здесь вообще теряется весь смысл многопоточности, ну кроме того, что она есть и работает. Эффекта от нее нет.

3. Лучше использовать `Task` вместо `Thread`.
4. Если же нужна реализация фокуса, состоящего в том, чтобы получать данные от внешнего процесса и одновременно по факту получения забирать их в другом потоке, то в бой вступают конкурентные коллекции, специально предназначенные для многопоточности. Моя любимая коллекция из таких - `BlockingCollection`.

Итак, попробую воплотить в коде то, что понаписал выше. На базе обычного консольного приложения.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Запускаем задачи
        Task task1 = new Producer("Передающая задача").Task;
        Task task2 = new Consumer("Принимающая задача").Task;

        // И ждем их завершения
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
        Console.WriteLine("Все задачи завершены.");

        // Ну и чтобы окошко сразу не закрылось
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
static class SharedRes
{
    // та самая блокирующая коллекция
    public static BlockingCollection<string> Data { get; } = new BlockingCollection<string>();
}

class Producer
{
    public Task Task { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Producer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Task = Task.Run(Run);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "ping",
            Arguments = "www.ya.ru",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (var pingProcess = new Process())
        {
            pingProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            pingProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
            pingProcess.Start();
            pingProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            pingProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        SharedRes.Data.CompleteAdding(); // отправить сигнал в BlockingCollection, что пора заканчивать
        Console.WriteLine(Name + " завершает работу.");
    }

    private static void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Мы в задаче один");
        SharedRes.Data.Add(e.Data);
        // немного упростил запись в лог
        File.AppendAllText("log.txt", e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    public Task Task { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Consumer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Task = Task.Run(Run);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        // Здесь коллекция ждет, пока не появится новый элемент или пока не поступит сигнал заканчивать
        foreach (string s in SharedRes.Data.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Мы в задаче два");
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Name + " завершает работу.");
    }
}
```

Можно еще упростить код и сделать его приятнее с точки зрения логичности и читабельности, а также не блокировать основной поток при ожидании дочерних, с помощью `async`/`await`, но это уже другая история.

**Вывод:**

```
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два

Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
Pinging ya.ru [87.250.250.242] with 32 bytes of data:
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
Reply from 87.250.250.242: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=249
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
Reply from 87.250.250.242: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=249
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
Reply from 87.250.250.242: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=249
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
Reply from 87.250.250.242: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=249
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два

Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
Ping statistics for 87.250.250.242:
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 16ms
Мы в задаче один
Мы в задаче два

Предающая задача завершает работу.
Принимающая задача завершает работу.
Все задачи завершены.
```

Comment: Task не является оберткой над Thread. Task не создает поток. `Task, она создает новые потоки только при необходимости, а когда завершается, не завершает поток, а оставляет его в режиме ожидания в пуле потоков ThreadPool` это попросту неверно.

Comment: `Task просто уделывает ручное создание потоков по производительности в разы.` это как сравнивать теплое с мягким.

Comment: Зато про мьютекс я с вами согласен.

Comment: У автора задача похожа на типичный [Producer/Consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/179763)

Comment: Task создает собственный поток только когда запущена с флагом TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning (в противном случае она выполняется на потоках из ThreadPool). Впрочем, делегат Process.OutputDataReceived и так по умолчанию запускается на ThreadPool. Мне кажется, здесь нет необходимости ни в Task, ни в Thread. task1 у вас бесполезно ждет в WaitForExit, а работу task2  мог бы выполнять основной поток.

Comment: Я согласен с  tym32167, утверждение что Task является оптимизированной оберткой над Thread лучше убрать. Оно может быть воспринято неправильно, как будто любой Thread можно преобразовать в Task, но это не так. Если поток выполнял длительную операцию, то перекладывание ее на Task (без флага LongRunning) может привести к исчерпанию ThreadPool.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо, убрал.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight по поводу того, что здесь можно обойтись вообще без тасок, я знаю, но в учебных целях пытался создать нечто похожее на то, что показал автор с явным запуском задач. И спасибо, что показали мне мой низкий уровень компетенций в знаниях о `ThreadPool`, я уже это изучил. Остался только один любознательный вопрос: у меня 8 ядер, откуда практически моментально берется 32767 потокв в пуле при запуске приложения, если запуск одного - это ~30мс. Или это просто размер пула, а потоки стартуют по мере надобности? В прочем, всё работает, и ладно. :)

Comment: а как вы получаете число 32767? Это действительно больше похоже на максимальное, чем на текущее.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight это и есть максимальное, просто не до конца понятно, что это значит.

Comment: Видимо 32767 - это значение по умолчанию для максимального числа потоков (которое задается параметром конфигурации https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/threading#maximum-threads ) - т.е. по умолчанию размер пула ограничен только размером переменной Int16. Например, для ASP.NET приложений, запускаемых в IIS, это значение будет меньше. Это теоретический максимум, а не реальное число созданных потоков (последнее можно получить как Maximum минус Available).