# Как передавать между классами стуктуру?

Tags: c#, классы, структуры

Увы не могу понять как передавать между классами структуру.

Знаю, можно передавать между классами  в классе общие ресурсы (переменные и т.д.), НО я бы именно **хотел узнать возможна ли передача именно структур между классами.**

Вот код :

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// передать структуру в поток и если че выключить её
 public struct SPEED
{
    public int speed; //скорость 
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // !!! вот тут пытасюсь заполнить и передать структуру
        SPEED speed_t = new SPEED();
        speed_t.speed  = 1;

        // Запускаем задачи
       // !!! вот тут ошибка
        Task task1 = new Producer("Передающая задача", speed_t).Task;
        Task task2 = new Consumer("Принимающая задача").Task;

        // И ждем их завершения
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
        Console.WriteLine("Все задачи завершены.");

        // Ну и чтобы окошко сразу не закрылось
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
static class SharedRes
{
    // та самая блокирующая коллекция
    public static BlockingCollection<string> Data { get; } = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    // содержит отменяющий токен, необходимый для прерывания ожидания блокирующей коллекции
    public static CancellationTokenSource Cts { get; } = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

public class Producer 
{
    public Task Task { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Producer(string name, ref SPEED speed_t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("скорость равна {0}", speed_t.speed);
        Name = name;
        Task = Task.Run(Run(speed_t.speed));
    }

    bool Examples(int i)
    {
        if(i==1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void Run(int i)
    {
        if (Examples(i) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Чепушня не отработала.");
            return 0;
        } 

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "ping",
            Arguments = "www.ya.ru",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (var pingProcess = new Process())
        {
            pingProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            pingProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
            pingProcess.Start();
            pingProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            pingProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        SharedRes.Cts.Cancel(); // отправить сигнал в BlockingCollection, что пора заканчивать
        Console.WriteLine(Name + " завершает работу.");
    }

    private static void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Мы в задаче один");
        SharedRes.Data.Add(e.Data);
        // немного упростил запись в лог
        File.AppendAllText("log.txt", e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    public Task Task { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Consumer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Task = Task.Run(Run);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            // Здесь коллекция ждет, пока не появится новый элемент или пока токен не получит отмену
            foreach (string s in SharedRes.Data.GetConsumingEnumerable(SharedRes.Cts.Token))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Мы в задаче два");
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            // Здесь можно вообще ничего не делать
            Console.WriteLine("Ожидание новых данных прервано: " + ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Name + " завершает работу.");
    }
}
```

Увы выдаёт мне множество ошибок :(

```
lovla_terminal10.cs(23,22): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Producer.Producer(string, ref SPEED)' has some invalid arguments
lovla_terminal10.cs(48,12): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
lovla_terminal10.cs(23,56): error CS1620: Argument `#2' is missing `ref' modifier
lovla_terminal10.cs(52,21): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)' has some invalid arguments
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
lovla_terminal10.cs(52,25): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `void' expression to type `System.Action'
lovla_terminal10.cs(69,13): error CS0127: `Producer.Run(int)': A return keyword must not be followed by any expression when method returns void
Compilation failed: 5 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Comment: `new Producer("Передающая задача", ref speed_t)` все модификаторы надо явно указывать

Comment: ну и если ты хочешь вернуть что-то из функции, в ее определении не должно стоять void

Comment: Вряд ли буду полезен, но всё же скажу, что со структурой можно работать как с обычным объектом какого-либо класса. По факту структуру можно заменить классом без методов, но с перегрузкой операторов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знакомый [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123414/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba/1123495#1123495) :)

Уберите `ref`, он здесь не нужен, измените конструктор как здесь:

```csharp
public Producer(string name, SPEED speed_t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("скорость равна {0}", speed_t.speed);
    Name = name;
    Task = Task.Run(() => Run(speed_t.speed));
}
```

И вот здесь просто `return`

```csharp
if (Examples(i) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Чепушня не отработала.");
    return;
}
```

Если вы о том, что возможно ли отправить структуру из одного потока в другой, то вот `BlockingCollection<string>`, просто поменяйте `string` на то что вам надо. Затем делайте `Add()` нужного вам экземпляра структуры, и забирайте его в итераторе принимающей задачи.

Comment: `ref` нужен чтобы структуру не копировать

Comment: @Grundy я знаю, для чего нужен `ref`, спасибо, но здесь слегка многопоточность.

Comment: и? это что-то меняет?

Comment: @Grundy Вопрос был про ошибки компиляции и можно ли в таск передать аргумент. Ошибки в коде я исправил, как передеть аргумент в `Task` тоже показал. Добавлять сюда пример с `deadlock(speed_t)` не вижу особого смысла, поэтому просто убрал `ref`.

Comment: так и не увидел ответ на вопрос в комментарии выше.

Comment: @Grundy Вопрос не по теме. Если вас интересует этот вопрос, создайте отдельный вопрос на StackOverflow, я или кто-нибудь другой, вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: Вопрос по содержимому ответа, так что все по теме :)