# C# - как вызывать `new Task()` для метода с аргументом?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

У меня простой вопрос.

Учусь работать с Task'ами.

Самый простой пример обычно такой:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            var t = Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()); Thread.Sleep(2000); });
            t.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("That's all!");
        }
    }
```

Но тут всё в лямбда - выражении, что не всегда удобно.
Ок, можно написать так:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

            var t1 = new Task(DoSomething);
            t1.Start();
            
            t1.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("That's all!");
        }

        static void DoSomething() {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hi at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

Здесь я отделил момент создания таски от её запуска, что иногда может быть очень удобно.
Но, как только появляется аргумент, это перестаёт работать:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

            var t1 = new Task(DoSomething);
            t1.Start();
            var xxx = 42;
            
            t1.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("That's all!");
        }

        static void DoSomething(int x) {
            Console.WriteLine($"x = {x} at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

В строке `var t1 = new Task(DoSomething)` я получаю ошибку `Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'`

Как можно создать задачу с аргументом, передающимся в неё?

Спасибо!

Дополнение
я нашел вот такое - довольно понятное - [объяснение](https://www.dotnetforall.com/correct-way-provide-input-parameter-task/).

Но там тоже пример какой то ущербный, компилятор ругается на него "Делегат "Action" не принимает аргументы 1." - вообще непонятная ошибка

Comment: Первая строчка в Яндексе по запросу "c# task with parameters": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225476/task-run-with-parameters

Comment: я читал этот вопрос-ответ... может, я чего то не понял, но там разбирается случай "запустить задачу с аргументом через Task.Run()". А я хочу создать задачу, а запустить её в другом месте кода.

Comment: Там есть и не только через `Run` в ответах. 
Можно создать `Action`, а потом передавать его в `Task`, вот примеры: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0
Сам конструктор `Task` принимает `Action`, который по той же документации: инкапсулирует метод, который не имеет параметров и не возвращает значений.
По этому, создать задачу так как вы хотите, вероятно не получится.

Comment: я, прежде чем написать вопрос, долго, часа два, мучился с этим Action, и я не понимаю синтаксис. я понимаю идею, но не понимаю, как это написать, чтобы компилятор не ругался. И всё таки, в задачу как то ведь можно передать аргументы? иначе вряд ли бы Task'и так широко использовались. Вопрос про Action: вот у меня уже есть процедура void DoSomething(int x){ ... } - а как мне из неё сделать Action<int>?

Comment: Вообще у меня было ОЧЕНЬ сложное решение для данной проблемы. Если подождёте, то я его найду (или восстановлю)

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей - спасибо, может быть, даже не стОит его восстанавливать, если оно такое сложное. я хочу просто освоить базовый синтаксис, подготовиться к собесам.

Comment: Да не, я использовал решение для другой задачи, а здесь можно сделать всё в сто раз проще парой строк. Просто сразу не дошло почему то) Сейчас опубликую ответ

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось решение довольно простым:

```cs
public static class PrTask
{
    public static Task Run(MulticastDelegate @delegate, params object[] args) => 
        Task.Run(() => @delegate.DynamicInvoke(args));

    public static Task Gen(MulticastDelegate @delegate, params object[] args) =>
        new Task(() => @delegate.DynamicInvoke(args));

    public static Action WithParams(this MulticastDelegate @delegate, params object[] args) =>
        () => @delegate.DynamicInvoke(args);
}
```

Пример использования:

```cs
// Метод можно объявлять как угодно
var method = (string x, string y) => Console.WriteLine(x + y);

PrTask.Run(method, "Runnig task like Task.Run()", ".").Wait();

var task = PrTask.Gen(method, "Runnig task by creating Task object", ".");
task.Start();
task.Wait();

var task2 = new Task(method.WithParams("gen Action from delegate", "."));
task2.Start();
task2.Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё таки я смог сделать это!

Спасибо всем, кто написал мне подсказки в комментариях.

Прикол был в том, что в создании Action не используется опаретор new() - раньше мне в NET такое не встречалось.

полностью решение выглядит так:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

            object xxx = 42; // аргумент, с которым я хочу вызвать функцию void DoSomething(int x)
            
            Action<object> myAction = (object obj) =>   // "переходник". Главное - не использовать new() при создании Action!
            {
                DoSomething((int)obj);
            };
            
            var t1 = new Task(myAction, xxx);
            t1.Start();
            
            
            t1.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("That's all!");
        }

        static void DoSomething(int x) {
            Console.WriteLine($"x = {x} at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: И всё-таки откажитесь от использования `new Task`. Нет смысла в предварительном создании таски в _холодном_ состоянии. Передавайте или параметры, или готовый делегат (Action) и вызывайте `Task.Run`.

Comment: А если мне надо периодически вызывать Task? Один и тот же?
Вообще, главные страдания - именно так, страдания! - от  отсутствия полного примера кода. Потому что придумать такой синтакис - нельзя... и получается: я понимаю, что надо сделать, а написать - не могу....

Comment: Ну вы попробуйте в конце своего кода ещё раз вызвать `t1.Start();`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - спасибо! Да, действительно, "Start may not be called on a task that has completed". Этого я не заметил. Получается, Task хорошо бы создавать каждый раз перед запуском?

Comment: Да, после завершения таски с ней ничего больше нельзя делать. Только создавать новую. И проще всего - с помощью `Task.Run`.

Comment: и всё таки: а что делать, если мне надо раз за разом вызывать одну и ту же задачу? Мне в голову приходит только два пути: 1) крутиться в цикле 2) использовать ContinueWith() - и этот метод выглядит... покультурнее.

Comment: Конструктор `new Task` для запуска потока устарел, и его не следует использовать. Использовать следует только `Task.Run` 2) В многопоточке смысла передавать в поток аргументы на старте как в метод, практически всегда нет. Почему? Почитайте про шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer. 3) Для всего остального есть лямбда - это хорошо, красиво и надёжно. Другими словами, вы нашли решение, которое на практике вам никогда не пригодится. И выглядит оно некрасиво. Решайте настоящие практические задачи, а не вот это вот всё. И главное: `Task` это не поток, `Task` - это ожидалка, а не выполнялка.

Comment: С другой стороны, сам по себе `Task` как ожидалка, используется для асинхронного программирования чаще, чем в контексте многопоточки, и да - это не одно и то же. В итоге, вы ни у кого не увидите в серьёзном коде `task.Wait();`, а увидите `await task;`. Так что добро пожаловать в асинхронный мир. **Хотите изучать `Task` - начните с `async/await`, таски там будут на каждом углу, но нигде не будет ни `task.Wait`, не `Task.Run`.** Что касается создания делегата `Action`, `new` там вызовется сам, хотите вы того или нет. И кстати в `Action` у вас та же лямбда.

Comment: _а что делать, если мне надо раз за разом вызывать одну и ту же задачу?_ - Producer/Consumer. Если кратко, то цикл внутри потока, да, с каналом передачи данных в него. Начните с `BlockingCollection`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1123495/373567