# C#, WinForms, Task: как запускать задачу несколько раз подряд?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

В продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1539667/), который я задал пару дней назад:

я пытаюсь сделать остановку - возобновление работы задачи (Task).

Пример я написал на WinForms, но вообще не важно, как именно - мне просто хочется понять, как работать с задачей. Но, как я понимаю, если задача перешла в состояние cancelled, то возобновить её выполнение не получается.

У меня в примере - форма с двумя кнопками, и текстбоксом, куда просто печатаются числа.

И старт-стоп работает только один раз.

Как это сделать более правильно?

Спасибо!

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
            startBtn.Click += StartBtn_Click;
            stopBtn.Click += StopBtn_Click;
        }

        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token;
        int cnt = 0;

        private void StartBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            var t = Task.Run(() => { do { ModifyTextBox(); Thread.Sleep(1000); } while (!token.IsCancellationRequested); }, token);
        }
        
        private void StopBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        
        private void ModifyTextBox() {
            Action modAction = () =>
            {
                textBox1.Text += (++cnt).ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            };

            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                textBox1.Invoke(modAction);
            else
                modAction();
        }
    }
```

**Продолжение**

я попробовал учесть рекомендации и написал такой код. Теперь я всю работу вынес в Action, а на основе Action стараюсь каждый раз создать при нажатии на кнопку НОВУЮ задачу. Даже объект task сделал локальным.

И всё таки получаю сообщение об ошибке 'Start may not be called on a task that has completed' при попытке второй раз нажать на startBtn.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
            startBtn.Click += StartBtn_Click;
            stopBtn.Click += StopBtn_Click;

            myAction = () =>
            {
                do {
                    ModifyTextBox();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                } while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
            };

        }

        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token;
        int cnt = 0;
        Action myAction;

        private async void StartBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            Task task = new Task(myAction, token);
            task.Start();
            await task;
            task.Dispose();
            task = null;
        }


        
        private void StopBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        
        private void ModifyTextBox() {
            Action modAction = () =>
            {
                textBox1.Text += (++cnt).ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            };

            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                textBox1.Invoke(modAction);
            else
                modAction();
        }
    }
```

**Третй и четвертый вариант:** после советов, которые мне дали в комментариях, я всё переписал под создание новой задачи при каждом нажатии на кнопку Start.

И передо мной был выбор: как же прерывать задачу? Есть два способа - просто return'ом после того, как стало истинным token.IsCancellationRequested или взывая token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

К сожалению, магия работает только в руках волшебников: при первом способе - задача во второй раз не запускается с сообщением "A task was canceled".

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            startBtn.Click += StartBtn_Click;
            stopBtn.Click += StopBtn_Click;

            token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
            myAction = () => {
                do {
                    ModifyTextBox();

                    if (token != null && token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                } while (true);
            };
        }

        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token;
        int cnt = 0;
        Action myAction;

        private async void StartBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            await Task.Run(myAction, token);
        }


        private void StopBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        
        private void ModifyTextBox() {
            Action modAction = () =>
            {
                textBox1.Text += (++cnt).ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            };

            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                textBox1.Invoke(modAction);
            else
                modAction();
        } 
    }
```

при втором способе при повторном нажатии на кнопку Start задача просто не продолжает работу. Ну, то есть, один раз кнопка срабаотывает - и всё.

Возможно, я не понимаю какой то тонкий момент, связанный со стартом задачи?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            startBtn.Click += StartBtn_Click;
            stopBtn.Click += StopBtn_Click;

            token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
            myAction = () => {
                do {
                    ModifyTextBox();

                    if (token != null)
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                } while (true);
            };
        }

        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token;
        int cnt = 0;
        Action myAction;

        private async void StartBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                await Task.Run(myAction, token);
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException ex) {

            }
        }


        private void StopBtn_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
            cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        
        private void ModifyTextBox() {
            Action modAction = () =>
            {
                textBox1.Text += (++cnt).ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            };

            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                textBox1.Invoke(modAction);
            else
                modAction();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: ИМХО, вы не должны хотеть делать такое тасками. Хотите паузу - завершите задачу, сохраните состояние, освободите ресурсы. Не, ну если хотите, запихните семафор и в случае, когда нужна пауза, вызывайте его, обратное действие делайте в случае возобновления.

Comment: В старые добрые времена, когда настоящие потоки (Thread) ещё не были преданы анафеме, такая проблема решалась элементарно: поток можно было приостановить (Suspend), а потом продолжить его исполнение (Resume). Раньше было лучше! (tm)

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем понимаю вот что: задачи - это как бы очень "легковестная" сущность, и создавать их можно по любой необходимости. Но объекты я могу создавать много раз подряд, А с задачами у меня этот фокус не получается. Как же правильно создавать несколько задач?

Comment: `public async Task MyTask(){ //Делаем что-то }`, далее `await MyTask();`, готово, вот вам каждый раз новая задача, которая выполняет то, что внутри. Суть задачи - выполнить что-то асинхронно, не более.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я попробовал дописать в StartBtn_Click() после строки с Task.Run следующее:         await task;
        task.Dispose();
        task = null; - но всё равно, при попытке повторно стартовать задачу я натыкаюсь на то, что 'A task was canceled' - то есть, НОВАЯ задача не создаётся. А нет для задач такого же new(), как для объектов?

Comment: Не `await task`, а повторно `task = new Task(myAction, token); await task;`, ну или `await Task.Run(...);`. Вы не делаете **новую** задачу, вы все еще используете старую.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - я постарался всё сделать так, как Вы посоветовали. Единственная разница - я стартовал только что созданную задачу при помощи task.Start(). И всё равно - мне это не помогло. Возможно, я Вас не так понял... Картина такая: есл я прерываю задачу просто проверкой token.IsCancellationRequested и return-ом - задача в следующий раз не стартует из аз того, что "A task was cancelled". Еслии же я пытаюсь вызывать token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested - то задача молча не стартует во второй раз. Сейчас подробно опишу в вопросе...

Comment: Вы делаете яичницу, берете сковородку, масло, разбили первое яйцо, затем взяли новое и разбили его, опять взяли новое и разбили, и так до тех пор, пока не наберете нужное кол-во. Вопрос: Вы можете взять уже разбитое яйцо и положить его как 2-е? Весьма странная задумка, верно? Ну вот таски это тоже самое. Таск - это одна конкретная задача, вы не должны их хранить гдет, вы не должны их перезапускать, вы должны каждый раз брать и запускать **новую** задачу, с новым токеном отмены, и так далее.

Comment: О, а последний комментарий помог!

Comment: Если анализировать ваш код, то вы делаете не то изначально. Обновление UI элементов не должно по сути быть в задаче, это не асинхронная задача. Вот допустим, нам надо вывести на экран текущее время, которое раз в секунду будет обновляться в UI, мы делаем простую Task с передачей прогресса `async Task Run(IProgress<DateTime> progress){ progress.Report(DateTime.Now); await Task.Delay(1000); }`, далее за пределами делаем `var progress = new Progress<DateTime>(time => TextBox.Text = time.ToString());`, ну и запускаем задачу, передав туда `progress`, готово. Как видите Task просто дает результат.

Comment: Ну а если нам не нужен прогресс, а просто результат, то `await Task<int> Run() { await Task.Delay(1000); return 1; }`, а дальше просто `var result = await Run(); TextBox.Text = result.ToString();`. Разделите ответственность, не мешайте все в одну кучу)

Answer (score 1):

по моему вы полезли... слишком далеко и не туда. надо вам анализировать состояние паузы - так добавьте соответствующее поле/свойство. надо анализировать это свойство для каждого потока - вынесите всё это в отдельный класс. в общем в двух словах (и читая задание по диагонали), как то так:

```
    private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isworking = false;
    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ispaused = !ispaused;
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isworking = true;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(processing);
        t.Start();
    }

    int counter = 0;
    bool isworking = false;
    bool ispaused = false;
    object locker = "";
    private void processing()
    {
        while (isworking)  {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if(!ispaused) {
                lock (locker) {
                    counter++;
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
                        lbl1.Content = counter.ToString();
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: собственно на "старт" добавляется новая задача. одна-две-тышча.
на "пауза" все задачи приостанавливаются. или привозобновляются.
на "стоп" все задачи сбрасываются. но... там косяк: чтоб задачи сбросились надо чтоб пауза больше секунды продержалась. да и в текущем виде после "стопа" каждая задача по разику увеличит счётчик.

Comment: А мне кажется, не туда пошли и вы тоже) Вместо того, чтобы создать полноценную задачу, асинхронную задачу, вы намешали все, и потоки, и локи, и диспетчер, когда как это решается стандартными инструментами в пару строк ( привет семафор).

Comment: так диспетчер - для возврата в базовый поток (тут не по теме, т.к. вриант для WPF, ну да ладно). локи - выполняют синхронизации потоков (собственно, семафор предназначен для того-же). А синхронно-асинхронно... конкретно в этом примере - разницы нет, имхо. Итого - то же самое решение в пару строк (остальное обвязка - обработчики кнопок), но без использования "стандартного" (когда он успел таким стать?) семафора. И да. лучше - можно. Всегда. Но, не правильнее ли будет это лучше продемонстрировать, чем просто упомянуть что оно есть?) тем более автору нужно не конкретное решение, а пример чегонить

Comment: 1. Диспетчер вам не нужен. 2. Локи делают асинхронное синхронным, они тут совсем не нужны. 3. Семафоры были [почти всегда](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) в .NET из коробки. 4. Семафоры не для "синхронизации" созданы, а для ограничения кол-ва (что как-раз в этой задачи и требуется). 5. "разницы нет" - разница в том, что у вас потоки, когда речь про таски (асинхронность), которых у вас практически нет....

Answer (score 1):

Что-то в кашу тут начинает превращаться все, видать без ответа не обойтись, чтож...

#### Пауза задачи

Сделать это можно, и довольно просто, но я на вашем месте сделал-бы не паузу, а сохранение текущего состояние, а потом возобновления с того-же места, создав новую `Task`, с новым токеном отмены. Задача - это единичная какая-то цель, не пытайтесь в ней сделать все и сразу.

Ну если прям нужна отмена, то вот самая элементарная задача с паузой:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new (1);

public async Task Run(IProgress<DateTime> progress)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            progress.Report(DateTime.Now);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}

private async void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<DateTime>(x => textBlock.Text = x.ToLongTimeString());
    await Run(progress);
}

private bool _isPause;
private async void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isPause)
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
        button.Content = "Пауза";
    }
    else
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        button.Content = "Возобновить";
    }

    _isPause = !_isPause;
}
```

Я не стал тут многого городить, и на многое "наплевал" (например `async void` - не самое лучшее), но для примера, сойдет.

Реализовано тут как видите на стандартном `SemaphoreSlim` - классе, который специально создан для ожидания `Task`'ами, обычно его используют в тех случаях, когда за раз должно выполняться только N задач разом, а не все сразу, ну и как по мне, N может быть и 1, что подходит под вашу задачу.

Теперь по порядку:

- `SemaphoreSlim` - Как и сказал выше, это ограничитель кол-ва работающих на данный момент задач (`Task`).
- `_semaphore.WaitAsync()` - Ждем, пока семафор даст добро на запуск, и если дает, занимаем "слот".
- `_semaphore.Release();` - Освобождаем занятый слот семафора.
- `IProgress<DateTime> progress` - Задача должна выполнять свою одну поставленную цель, не нагружайте ее еще и выводом на экран чего либо, это не ее обязанность, там этого быть не должно. Нужно получать в реальном времени некий прогресс, используйте специально созданный для этого `IProgress`, это в некотором роде событие, которое мы также можем оповестить об изменении.
- `progress.Report(DateTime.Now)` - оповещаем прогресс об изменении значения в `Task`.
- `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` - Просто ждем 1 секунду.
- `new Progress<DateTime>(...)` - Делаем условного "читателя" прогресса, который уже будет что-то делать, в моем случае просто меняет значение в UI.
- `await Run(progress)` - Запускаем новую задачу.

Остальное повторяется, там разберетесь.

#### Повторный запуск задачи

Как я и сказал ранее, новая задача означает повторное пересоздание всего, от самой задачи, то токенов отмены. В коде выше, чтобы запустить повторную задачу, нужно просто сделать по новой `await Run(progress);`, если нам нужно несколько крутящихся задач разом, то делаем что-то такое:

```
var task1 = Run(progress);
var task2 = Run(progress);
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Тут можем и массив использовать, без проблем, главное, что мы создаем таску, которая сразу запускается, и потом все их ждем. Считайте в целом таски и токены, это одноразовыми объектами, раз использовали и забыли про них.

В целом, как-то так. Да, вы можете тут и без семафоров реализовать, но давайте использовать все по своему назначению. В общем, удачи.